# Как использовать классы в главном скрипте программы

Tags: python-3.x, ооп

Допустим у меня есть следующий класс и еще 2 класса схожих с этим:

```
class calc:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
    
    def mult(self):
        return a*b
```

И есть главный скрипт -main.py где человек выбирает класс калькулятор или другой класс и мне нужно чтобы пользователь ввел 2 числа.
Это должно выглядеть так?

```
If player_input == calc:
   a = calc(input(),input())
   print(a.mult())
```

Comment: Зависит от того, что у вас в player_input. Если там строка, полученная из инпута, то и сравнивать надо со строкой: `If player_input == "calc":` В остальном вроде всё нормально выглядит. А в чём конкретно вопрос-то? У вас ваш код работает не так, как вы ожидаете? Или вы просто хотите узнать, насколько он соответствует хорошему стилю?

Comment: Все, понял. Вопрос был в правильности логики.